# web service generating proxy problem

Tags: c#, web-services

I can invoke and test web service but when i try to generate proxy i can see this in log...

> Generating proxy WARNING: value type
>   package prefix is ignored for the
>   types defined in the schema that has
>   same target namespace as the target
>   namespace of wsdl: "TRINITY"
>
> WARNING: value type package prefix is
>   ignored for the types defined in the
>   schema that has same target namespace
>   as the target namespace of wsdl:
>   "TRINITY" WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpPost": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpPost"
>   that does not contain a SOAP Binding. 
>   Only soap:binding is supported.
>   WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpGet": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpGet" that
>   does not contain a SOAP Binding.  Only
>   soap:binding is supported.
>
> WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpPost": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpPost"
>   that does not contain a SOAP Binding. 
>   Only soap:binding is supported.
>   WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpGet": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpGet" that
>   does not contain a SOAP Binding.  Only
>   soap:binding is supported.
>
> WARNING: value type package prefix is
>   ignored for the types defined in the
>   schema that has same target namespace
>   as the target namespace of wsdl:
>   "TRINITY" WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpPost": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpPost"
>   that does not contain a SOAP Binding. 
>   Only soap:binding is supported.
>   WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpGet": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpGet" that
>   does not contain a SOAP Binding.  Only
>   soap:binding is supported.
>
> WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpPost": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpPost"
>   that does not contain a SOAP Binding. 
>   Only soap:binding is supported.
>   WARNING: ignoring port
>   "wsBibliografijeHttpGet": because it
>   references
>   "{TRINITY}wsBibliografijeHttpGet" that
>   does not contain a SOAP Binding.  Only
>   soap:binding is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the target namespace for the Schema Element